# Google IO 2013 App Mystery Values

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, tile, googleio

I'm trying to make use of the [`SVGTileProvider`](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/SVGTileProvider.java#61) that is found in the [Google IO 2013 app](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/). I can't figure out exactly how to position an image on the Google Map though. I've narrowed it down to this section of the class. These aren't lat/long coordinates however somehow they must be coming from lat/long coordinates. Does anyone know what these are or where they come from?

```
mBaseMatrix.setPolyToPoly(
    new float[]{
        0, 0,
        limits.width(), 0,
        limits.width(), limits.height()
    }, 0,
    new float[]{
        40.95635986328125f, 98.94217824936158f,
        40.95730018615723f, 98.94123077396628f,
        40.95791244506836f, 98.94186019897214f
    }, 0, 3);
```

**Update**

The first set of mystery numbers roughly translates to lat/long 37.783887,-122.405107.

**Update 2**

These methods help me convert latitude to a y value and vice versa. How can I do this for X and Longitude?

```
public static double y2lat(double aY) {
    return Math.toDegrees(2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(Math.toRadians(aY))) - Math.PI / 2);
}
public static double lat2y(double aLat) {
    return Math.toDegrees(Math.log(Math.tan(Math.PI / 4 + Math.toRadians(aLat) / 2)));
}
```

Comment: Is it suppose to be Madrid, Spain? Why arent they lat long values?

Comment: No. I'm currently trying to display an image over a building in Atlanta, GA. After that I'll have a few other locations.

Comment: I typed it in wrong, but its still not atlanta. Google does take Lat longs to that accuracy though. it turned 40.98 into a long value

Comment: I said in my question that these are NOT lat/long values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out these are World Coordinates.

Here is some java code to translate from lat/long to x/y.

```
public static float lat2y(double aLat) {
    return (float) (((1 - Math.log(Math.tan(aLat * Math.PI / 180) + 1 / Math.cos(aLat * Math.PI / 180)) / Math.PI) / 2 * Math.pow(2, 0)) * 256);
}
public static float lon2x(double lon) {
    return (float) ((lon + 180f) / 360f * 256f);
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer!  Thanks @Sababado :-)

Comment: Extensive and exhaustive Google searching. I couldn't honestly say where I found them now. Probably somewhere when I looked up how to convert world coordinates in Java

Answer (score 1):

See the class TileProjection I posted in the answer to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382823/google-maps-api-v2-draw-part-of-circle-on-mapfragment/20408460#20408460) question. If Sababado is right, that the numbers are WorldCoordinates, then this class should help you to convert them.
You can find the formulas also [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates).