# Custom Google Map Types

Tags: android, google-maps, gis, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm looking for a way to use custom map tiles with the Google Map API V2 for Android.

I'm writing an application that will create it's own maps in real time with data that are comming from a robot.

The application need to show to the operator this map. The operator need to interact with this map, letting way points, etc.

I want to use the GoogleMap engine in order to do the same that in this page :

http://cdn.mikecouturier.com/blog.mikecouturier.com/tilesgenerator/index.html

The problem is, this guy use the **[javascrip API]**

But me, I want to use the **[Android API]**

Are there any way to use Custom tiles map on android with the GoogleMap Engine ?

Thank's a lot

*PS : I'm already looking how to use ArcGIS. But, i prefer using API without paying license, thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using GoogleMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NONE) you will get an empty map.

Using e.g. the CanvasTileProvider I have described in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382823/google-maps-api-v2-draw-part-of-circle-on-mapfragment/20408460#20408460) you may then draw anything into the tiles.