# Is there a way to draw geotiff as tiles in Android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, geotiff

If I have layered GeoTiff is there a way I can open that and return the image as a tile or tiles.  Thought being that I can put a decent size geotiff in my apk and use that as either tiles or groundoverlay when offline.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the GeoTIFF format, but if you know how to render it into a canvas you can use the CanvasTileProvider I described in the answer of [Google Maps API v2 draw part of circle on MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382823/google-maps-api-v2-draw-part-of-circle-on-mapfragment).