# How to join multiple markers on the map with arrow headed poly-line to show directions of travelling?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am a newbie to the android and currently working on the Google-map API.
I am able to plot multiple markers on the map but want to join multiple markers with poly line.I have referred [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/) for the directions concern but it is for two points only. 
Below is the code for the Activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;
// latitude and longitude
double latitude;
double longitude;
String newtime;
ArrayList<LatLng> points;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    points.add(new LatLng(21.114369, 79.049423));
    points.add(new LatLng(21.113913, 79.049203));
    points.add(new LatLng(21.113478, 79.048736));
    points.add(new LatLng(21.113002, 79.048592));
    points.add(new LatLng(21.112857, 79.047315));
    points.add(new LatLng(21.112997, 79.046741));
    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    newtime = sdfDateTime.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    // googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    drawMarker(points);

}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void drawMarker(ArrayList<LatLng> l) {
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        latitude = l.get(i).latitude;
        longitude = l.get(i).longitude;
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Bus")
                .snippet(newtime);
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(l.get(0).latitude, l.get(0).longitude)).zoom(18).build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}

}
```

Please help/guide me to achieve the task.

~Thanks.

Comment: Mean, each point to another.

Comment: Yes sir, I want to draw a poly line which is forming a route by joining every marker.

Comment: Here locations is your custom class?

Comment: Yes Locations class is used for storing the Lat-Lng points in an array list of locations points.

Comment: Here, no need to create separate class na, There is once class called `LatLng` which stores these informations.

Comment: I am passing the two values for plotting the marker on the map and there are multiple locations having multiple latitude and longitude thats why i am passing an array list of multiple points to the drawMarker() method.

Comment: I understood, but here no need to create class `Locations` to store latitude, longitude, because android default provides `LatLng` class.

Comment: Okay Sir I will change the code accordingly but the main issue is to joining the markers.

Answer (score 3):

Modify your `drawMarker()` to the following:-

```
private void drawMarker(ArrayList<LatLng> l) {
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions

    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
    options.color(Color.RED);

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        options.add(l.get(i));
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(l.get(i)).title("Bus")
                .snippet(newtime);
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }

    googleMap.addPolyline(options);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(l.get(0).latitude, l.get(0).longitude)).zoom(18).build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}
```

Here it will add lines with red color, to change colors as your wish just modify the `options.color()`.

Comment: Its good but I want to draw the lines direction wise so can you please please help me l'll more?

Comment: @SwapnilLanjewar You can do it, I also doesn't know, need to write custom logic, you can find reference for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382823/google-maps-api-v2-draw-part-of-circle-on-mapfragment/20408460#20408460

Comment: OK Sir and I am really very thankful for your support, time and precious help!

Comment: @SwapnilLanjewar Its my pleasure