# How to set Google map on max zoom level to 30 in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, zooming

*Let me tell you from the start it doesn't work:*

```
mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(30.0f);
```

**I know Google Maps doesn't allow to zoom above 21 but I saw in Javascript you can add a new maptype and set max zoom level to 30 or whatever you want.** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay

I find a link for Java to add new Tile but I dont understand how to use for adding new map type and set max zoom: [Google Maps API v2 draw part of circle on MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382823/google-maps-api-v2-draw-part-of-circle-on-mapfragment/20408460#20408460)

How to set Google map on max zoom level to 30 in Android?

***Yes, maybe the reason Android SDK is only on V2 so does not have the same feature set (yet) as the JS SDK.***

**But maybe there is another way or hack something. Is there any other solution?**

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the android docs: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory

It states:
[image]

"the desired zoom level, in the range of 2.0 to 21.0. Values below this range are set to 2.0, and values above it are set to 21.0. Increase the value to zoom in. Not all areas have tiles at the largest zoom levels."

I believe the reason you can do this in JavaScript is because the JS google maps SDK is currently on V3, whereas the Android SDK is only on V2 so does not have the same feature set (yet) as the JS SDK.

Comment: @Hilalkah please accept the answer if it helped you